# Finding the inverse of divisor functions in terms of $\mu$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

How would I find the inverse of $τ(n)=\sum_{d|n}1$ and $\sigma(n)=\sum_{d|n}d$ in terms of $\mu$? Where $µ$ is the Mobius function.

So I know $τ=u*u$ and $\sigma=N*u$ and also $u*\mu=I$ but I cant quite see how to get to the final steps.

I know I need to show that $τ^{-1}=\mu*\mu$ but can't quite see how to get to this step?

I think $\sigma^{-1}=N*\mu$ is that right?

Comment: (arithm function, convolution operator) is a Abelian Group

Comment: typo? $τ^{-1} = \mu * \mu$ ?

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula

Comment: Isn't it enough to just compute $\tau \ast (\mu\ast\mu) = I$? Or do you also need an argument for why that is the case?

Comment: Looks like another typo. Since $\sigma = N\ast u$, and $\sigma$ is positive, it can't be that $\sigma^{-1} = N\ast u$.

Comment: Sorry getting confused with my mu's and u's. How does $\tau \ast (\mu\ast\mu) = I$?

Comment: Or more so what I mean is, since $\mu*\mu$ is the inverse,we see that $\tau \ast (\mu\ast\mu) = I$ but how would I know in the first place to pick $\mu*\mu$ in order to calculate for other examples?